# Network bottleneck/throttling issue

Tags: networking, internet

It's my first day at a new company and i've been given the task to find out an issue with the internet connection.

I noticed that whilst I was downloading a large file, the network grinds to a halt, except for my download.

At first I thought it was the internet connection/modem but it seems that whilst the lockdown occurs, I am unable to access any network device.

Has anyone experienced this before and if so, do you have any pointers?

Looking at the setup. They have an DSL modem that connects to a 10/100 switch. There are only 5-6 computers on the network.

Cheers

Gavin

Comment: You need to provide hardware details to get real help

Comment: This is a QoS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) problem: Any solution is likely to involve prioritising some traffic classes over others. For example, making VoIP and SSH traffic take priority over bulk downloads. How you actually achieve this depends on the hardware you have available :)

Comment: Yes, please provide what kind of DSL modem/router you have.

Comment: Hardware: bt2700hgv - 7.6mb up, 765k down. Connected using a single Cat5 cable to a 10 port 10/100 netgear unmanaged switch (unsure of model at the moment) which is then connected to other devices on teh networking using cat5 cables.

The provider is suggesting that at 700kb/s I am using the FULL potential of the line which is why no one else can use the connection.

I personally think that is a load of rubbish as i have had large files downloading at 2mb/s whilst also streaming video, surfing etc.

Thanks for moving and commenting ;)

Gav

Comment: lol oops: 7.6mb down, 768kb up ;)

Comment: Some netgear routers, targeted at home users, have this problem when you hit around 500-700kb/s speeds. They are just unreliable. Its also likely, as pointed out, thats its a QoS problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would do some additional troubleshooting.

1- Can you replicate the problem on other PCs?
2- Can you replicate the problem plugged into a different port on the switch?
3- Does the problem occur if you are plugged into the router directly, or if you are using wireless?
4- If you can, can you swap out the broadband router and replicate the problem?

BTW -- my bet is the switch.

Comment: As has been pointed out, it is most likely a bad switch or a QOS problem.  What model switch?  Have you check the router config?